# How to delete telegram bot own messages?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

What I want to achieve is that before I post new message via bot X I delete the previous messages that are posted by the same bot X. I'm looking at the method `bot.delete_message` but that requires `message_id` what means that I would need to store the id some-have locally. Is there any way around this? Like fetching bot own messages?

Answer (score 0):

```
import python-telegram....
import time

current_message = None


def current_message_updater(new_message):
    global current_message
    # delete last message
    if not current_message:
        current_message.delete()
    # send new message will return its message object,
    # we assign it into current_message variable
    new = bot.send_message(....., text=new_message)
    current_message = new


# if all of this is happening in the same function
# you can do like this

def my handler():
    message = bot.send_message(...., text="hi new user")
    time.sleep(1)
    message.delete()
    another_one = bot.send_message(..., text="How are u?")
```

Comment: Will not work for me. As the script is run by a cron job so I can't store stuff in memory. I ended up storing last message if in a file and then reading it.

Comment: There is a method in tellegram library which returns [message history](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_history?highlight=history#pyrogram.Client.get_history),
when a user message the bot, the bot checks the history and takes the last message send by bot -- if no message found the bot ignores the following else take the last message delete it and send the new one

Comment: Yes but I need the bot own message history, what seems not possible.

Comment: Bot doesnt have saved messgae if that what you meant, unless its possible.